# Having trouble implementing JSON_EXTRACT in MYSQL on a column of data

Tags: mysql, moodle

A cell value outputs the following result:

- Column 0 = {"1": "Strongly disagree", "2": "Disagree", "3": "Neutral", "4": "Agree", "5": "Strongly agree"}

I'm trying to get the values in this cell.

- Column 1 = Strongly Disagree
- Column 2 = Disagree
- Column 3 = Neutral
- Column 4 = Agree
- Column 5 = Strongly Agree

Sample Code:

```
SELECT
,qq.extradata                     AS 'column 0'
,JSON_EXTRACT(qq.extradata,'$.1') AS 'column 1'
,JSON_EXTRACT(qq.extradata,'$.2') AS 'column 2'
,JSON_EXTRACT(qq.extradata,'$.3') AS 'column 3'
,JSON_EXTRACT(qq.extradata,'$.4') AS 'column 4'
,JSON_EXTRACT(qq.extradata,'$.5') AS 'column 5'
FROM {questionnaire_question} AS qq
```

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html says:

> Names of keys must be double-quoted strings or valid ECMAScript identifiers...
>
> A period followed by a key name names the member in an object with the given key. The key name must be specified within double quotation marks if the name without quotes is not legal within path expressions (for example, if it contains a space).

Another example of a key name that is not a valid identifier is your `1`, `2`, `3`, ...

So you should be able to get the value you need by using double quote marks around the name:

```
JSON_EXTRACT(qq.extradata,'$."1"')
```

You probably also want to unquote the result, because it will be returned as a JSON string scalar with double-quotes.

```
JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(qq.extradata,'$."1"'))
```